# How to plot meshgrid on a map in python without changing the background every time?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, netcdf4

I am trying to plot a meshgrid on a map in python using netCDF4 in python. Following was the code that was used.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset as netcdf_dataset
import numpy as np
import print
from cartopy import config
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import PIL
from PIL import Image
import cv2
%cd /content/drive/My Drive/Project/Fogs


for i in range(0,608):

   sst = fh.variables['Fog_Mask'][i+1][:] - fh.variables['Fog_Mask'][i][:]

   lats = fh.variables['latitude'][:]
   lons = fh.variables['longitude'][:]
   ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
   ax.contourf(lons, lats, sst)
   ax.coastlines()
   m = globals()
   n = locals()

  exec("plt.savefig('example{}.png',bbox_inches='tight')".format(i+1) , m , n)
```

But I find that for certain images the background is different.

[image]

[image]

Now, for some reason, I can't share the data but latitude and longitude are masked arrays that shall be used while plotting and Fog_Mask is another masked array that is plotted on the maps. I want the boundaries to be the same for all the figures but that is not happening.

PS: I don't want to go to street view and do this. Please suggest a pythonic way to reproduce the maps only.

Comment: On each plot, use the same `ax.set_extent([LL_lon, UR_lon, LL_lat, UR_lat])`.

Comment: side note, you do not need that `exec` command

Comment: `plt.savefig('example{}.png'.format(i+1), bbox_inches='tight')` will get you what you want